# QGIS Modeler variable input for Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-modeler

I tried the following expression to call the variable number as input on QGIS raster calculator, but it doesn't like it. In other words, what is the syntax to be used to call the number? ((version QGIS 3.22).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It think it’s @number

Comment: no luck with @number also

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Raster Calculator` from SAGA, and put sommething like that:
[image]
In the formula, the `a` means band one of the raster.

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes, please click on « answered »! Thanks